# Is it possible to make intent not to start a new activity, but only be received by existing one?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to send an Intent from a service by startActivity(...) method.
I also want this intent to be received if the Activity is running (and/or paused)
If activity not running, I do not want to start it, I want the intent just get lost.
Is it possible to implement such behavior?

Comment: I believe you can use a Broadcast for this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have your activity register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in onCreate() and unregister it in onPause(). That will ensure that your receiver is only active for the duration of your activity.

```
public void onStart() {
  mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(...);
  registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}
...
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
```

[registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) is defined in Context.

Answer (score 0):

> If activity not running, I do not want to start it,

I don't know about the part, but if you don't want to create another instance of the same activity when there is already one running, you may want to try `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on your Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```